# How to upload lines created by joining longitude, latitude pairs?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

The data in a Mapinfo table contain longitude and latitude pairs. I have joined the point pairs using :

1. Making the table mappable
2. Setting the projection to WGS84 and
3. update TABLE set obj = createline(x1,y1,x2,y2)
4. The lines are created and
5. Map Catalog is created using Easyloader

I wanted to upload it using Easyloader but it shows an error message that it could not open the table mytable.tab (mytable is a tab file). What is the process of uploading any table to the database?

The database is MSSQL.

Edit ---------------------------------------------------
After Peter Horsbøll Møller's suggestion I saved a copy and the error was

> A .Net Framework error occoured during execution of user defined
>   routine or aggregate "geometry": System.FormatException:24117:The
>   lineString input is not valid because it does not have enough distinct
>   po Data Values:18418

Comment: it is MS SQL Server 2008 and not mySQL, right?

Comment: @Peter Horsbøll Møller yes it is MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the type of table isn't supported by EasyLoader. Is it a regular MapInfo tab file?
You try to use Save Copy as to make sure it is a "plain" tab file and then upload this copy using EasyLoader.
You could also try to just use Save copy as and save it directly to the database from within MapInfo Pro.

Comment: Thanks but I got other error as I saved the copy I have added it in edit.

Comment: + Thanks it is the right answer. Also for future reference the data was actually repeated i.e to and from data was same(same latitude and longitude joining same latitude and longitude) and hence produced the error.